# Subview frame in scrollview behaving differently on simulator and device

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios-simulator, frame, device

So in layoutSubviews, I'm calling positionTextView to adjust the frame of my UIScrollView subview (a UIImageView), which contains the following code.

```
CGRect frame = informationTextView.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, self.contentOffset.y + 414-44);
informationTextView.frame = frame;
overlayView.frame = frame;
```

So on the simulator, the subview's frame location remains fixed (according to the contentOffset), but when testing on a device, the frame is moving, as if it wasn't taking the contentOffset into account.

Am I missing a difference between the behavior of the simulator and a device?

Comment: There are subtle differences between the simulator and the device in some cases, which is why device testing is important.  THe UIScrollView will not call layoutSubviews whenever the contentOffset changes, so... if your intended behavior is to have your text view remain static within the scrollview as it scrolls, then you should probably set the frame in didScroll: ... however, why not just overlay the view on top of the scrollview (not as a subview) so you can set it in layoutSubviews instead of whenever the scroll view scrolls.  EDIT: I'm not sure exactly why the discrepancy is occurring.

Comment: That's a very informative comment, thanks! You should consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: I just realized that the problem just solved itself by itself... I'm not sure whether it happened when I cleaned my product, resulting in the code that handle the adjustment of the frame being updated or not.